# How to retrieve from word table to an array?

Tags: ms-word

I want to retrieve data from my word table and store them to an array. for example extract the name column to store in tablName

this my table

```
---------------------------------
| N° |  name  |  Bond  |  Delay |
---------------------------------
|1   |        |        |        |
---------------------------------
|2   |        |        |        |
---------------------------------
|3   |        |        |        |
---------------------------------
```

this is my array tablName

```
-----------------------------
|      |      |      |      |
-----------------------------
```

this is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim tablName() 

If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To n
        tablName(i - 2) = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
    Next
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(3, 2).Range.Text  
    MsgBox tablName(0)            /* The error appears here: subscript out of range error */
```

What is the probleme, i search but not find the problem

Comment: You haven't given your array a size. You would declare it like Dim tableName(5) as String. You can change the size during code execution using Redim. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm You also haven't assigned a value to n in For i = 2 to n.

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer
When you create an array(), it's dimensionless so you must redim the array for use it with this:

```
Dim tabLots As Variant
    tabLots = Array()

ReDim tabLots (nb_lot)
```

this is my finally code

```
Dim tabLots As Variant
    tabLots = Array()

ReDim tabLots (nb_lot)
For i = 2 To n + 1
    tabLots (i - 2) = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
Next i
```